# How to give slide down effect when hover?

Tags: html, css

**HTML**

```
<div class="team_hover">
    <div style="color:#fff;text-align:center;width:200;">
        <p style="margin:5px 0 0 0;font-size:11px;">Admin</p>
        <p style="margin:0;">Marketing</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="hover-div">
    <div class="div_mark">
        <div style="color:#fff;text-align:center;">
            <p style="margin:5px 0 0 0;font-size:11px;">Admin</p>
            <p style="margin:0;">Marketing</p>
        </div>
        <div class="team_back">             
            <p>Team 1</p>
            <p>Team 2</p>
            <p style="border-bottom: 1px solid #ff9900;">Team 3</p>
            <p>Add New Team</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.team_hover{
    background:#ffcc00;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1;
}
.div_mark{
    background:#ffcc00;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1;
}

.hover-div{
    display:none;
    transition:all 0.9s linear 0s;
 }
 .team_hover:hover + .hover-div {
    display:block;
 }
 .hover-div:hover {
    display:block;
 }
```

Here I can show hidden div when hover. I want to slide down a second div on hover.

**How do you do this without jQuery?**

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sg1we9qu/)

Comment: use `@keyframes` animation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make a slide down effect you can play with the position of your div, like this :

```
.hover-div{
    position:absolute;
    top:-130px;
    display:block;
    transition:all 0.9s linear 0s;
}
.team_hover:hover + .hover-div {
    top:0px;    
    display:block;
 }

.hover-div:hover {
        display:block;
        top:0px;
 }
```

Here is your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sg1we9qu/1/) updated

Comment: Hi, thanks. But here hover-div display:block mode. I want to hide that div when at page load time. http://jsfiddle.net/sg1we9qu/2/

Comment: I don't know exactly what you want with that information, can you ask an other question with more information about your issue ?